# Array Values are Snowballing

Tags: jquery, arrays, return-value

I am new to working with Arrays first and foremost. I am collecting all of the css background-color values from a series of Img tags and building an array with it. But each value in the array is a snowball of the value before it. How do I go about outputting EACH value within the array?
Here is my code:

```
var slideArray = [];
$('.home-rotator-wrap .cycle-slideshow > div img').each(function() {
    slideArray.push($(this).css('background-color'));
    console.log(slideArray);
});
```

And what me console shows me:

```
["rgb(255, 0, 0)"]
["rgb(255, 0, 0)", "rgb(0, 255, 0)"]
["rgb(255, 0, 0)", "rgb(0, 255, 0)", "rgb(0, 0, 255)"]
["rgb(255, 0, 0)", "rgb(0, 255, 0)", "rgb(0, 0, 255)", "rgb(0, 0, 0)"]
```

I need each one of the values of the four img tags, but need to return each one separately.

All of this in order to be able to cycle through the values of the array and return each one in a timed animation. It is for the background of a page and needs to match the animation of a cycle2 slider.

Comment: simplified code:`var slideArray =$('.home-rotator-wrap .cycle-slideshow > div img').map(function () {
    return $(this).css("background-color");
});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works. You just put the `console.log` statement in the wrong spot, so it logs the progress of the array after each loop. If you only want it to log once, move it outside of the loop.

---

BTW, you don't have to manually push those values onto the array. You can use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) for that:

```
var slideArray = $('.home-rotator-wrap .cycle-slideshow > div img').map(function() {
    return $(this).css('background-color');
}).get();
```

For better performance, you should consider using the static `$.css` method instead of creating a new object for each element in the collection:

```
var slideArray = $('.home-rotator-wrap .cycle-slideshow > div img').map(function() {
    return $.css(this, 'background-color');
}).get();

console.log(slideArray);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I know the best way to go about building an array for instances like this.